# Is it faster to use a persistent variable than to reallocate memory each function call by e.g. zeros() if a function is called often?

Tags: performance, matlab

Assume I have a function which is called often, say by an ODE-solver or similar. Is it faster to use a persistent variable than to reallocate it each time?
That is, which function would be faster and what is best practice?

```
function ret=thisfunction(a,b,c)
  A = zeros(3)
  foo = 3;
  bar = 34;
  % ...
  % process some in A
  % ...
  ret = A\c;
end
```

or

```
function ret=thatfunction(a,b,c)
  persistent A foo bar
  if isempty(A); 
    A=zeros(3); 
    foo = 3;
    bar = 34;
  end
  % ...
  % process some in A
  % ...
  ret = A\c;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to best practice, I would dissuade you from using persitent variables in this manner, for two reasons.

Persitent variables can be cleared externally, e.g. running clear('thatfunction') from any other function that has "thatfunction" on the path would reset your persitent variables in "thatfunction". As such, it's possible that they'll be unwittingly reset elsewhere. This may not be a problem for you in this context, but if you want to keep results between function calls (which is the primary point of persitent variables) this can cause you headaches.

Also, if you modify them, you'll have to remember to clear them when you're done running in-order to reset your workspace to a clean state. Otherwise if you (or someone else) runs your program again without clearing your persitent variable(s) first, the results from the previous run. This isn't an issue if they're read-only, but you cannot enforce that they will be.

Answer (score 2):

Which one is faster can only be proven by test, as it may depend on variable size etc. However, I would say that if it is not required, it is usually also not recommended to use persistent variables.

Therefore I would definately recommend you to use option number one.

---

Sidenote: You probably want to check whether it exists rather than whether it is empty. Furthermore I don't know what happens to your A when you leave the function scope, if you want to define it as persistent or global you may have to do it one level higher.

Comment: I will write a test... On the sidenote, I think it will always exist since it is initilized by the persitent statement?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a single function such as this to test I have found that it's very easy to setup a parent function, run the function you are testing say, 10 million times and time the results.  Then consider the difference in time AND the possible trade off or side effects of using a persistent variable here.  It may not be worth it if the difference is a few percent over 10 million calls and you are actually only going to call the function 10 thousand times in application.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, I will do such a test. How about best practice?